# iOS - Can't trace this crash error

Tags: ios, crash-reports, crashlytics

I'm using Crashlytics 3.6.0 and I've been getting a couple of crash reports lately that I can't read/understand. They seem to only happen on iOS 8 (can't confirm this 100% though).

```
Thread : Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x197fcfbd0 objc_msgSend + 16
1  UIKit                          0x18c035c60 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 124
2  UIKit                          0x18c293e7c -[UISwitch _handleLongPressNL:] + 424
3  UIKit                          0x18c1af508 _UIGestureRecognizerSendActions + 276
4  UIKit                          0x18c048050 -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:buttonEvent:] + 580
5  UIKit                          0x18c4b420c ___UIGestureRecognizerUpdate_block_invoke662 + 60
6  UIKit                          0x18c00c530 _UIGestureRecognizerRemoveObjectsFromArrayAndApplyBlocks + 292
7  UIKit                          0x18c00a8dc _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 2504
8  UIKit                          0x18c0461f8 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1044
9  UIKit                          0x18c045898 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 660
10 UIKit                          0x18c018fa8 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 264
11 infinight                      0x1003ebe00 -[IBGMethodSwizzler sendEvent:] (IBGMethodSwizzler.m:103)
12 UIKit                          0x18c2b7f58 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 14992
13 UIKit                          0x18c017510 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1616
14 CoreFoundation                 0x18781e9ec __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
15 CoreFoundation                 0x18781dc90 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 264
16 CoreFoundation                 0x18781bd40 __CFRunLoopRun + 712
17 CoreFoundation                 0x1877490a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
18 GraphicsServices               0x1908eb5a4 GSEventRunModal + 168
19 UIKit                          0x18c07e3c0 UIApplicationMain + 1488
20 infinight                      0x10013af44 main (main.m:16)
21 libdyld.dylib                  0x19862aa08 start + 4
```

Could anyone help me identify the error? I can't reproduce the error -- it doesn't happen on my device or on the simulator. But I've been getting a fair amount of crash reports like these in the last couple of days from test users.

Comment: Start by updating your question with relevant code around line 103 of IBGMethodSwizzler.m.

Comment: "objc_msgSend" is a good indicator that you're trying to send a message to some object that doesn't exist any more.  Perhaps you can track it by knowing what a `UISwitch` connects to.  If you are swapping method implementations (swizzle), that could point to the problem.

Comment: You are completely right @PhillipMills ! I managed to track the error down by installing iOS 8.1 simulator and enabling Zombie Objects. What am I doing wrong? I updated the question at the end

Comment: My next step would be to use Instruments to track allocation history and see where it was unexpectedly released.  (Or maybe you'll find that obvious depending on how the `NamedUISwitch` was created and used.)

Comment: I simply alloc, init the NamedUISwitch in every Cell of my TableView, so multiple instances are created. How should I handle this? And how come this crash doesn't occur on iOS 9?

Comment: I've tried using Instruments but I can't seem to get it to work for me the way it should. I think the issue is all about the TableViewCells but I can't figure it out.

Comment: It's going to be hard for anyone else to guess based on current information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an error that only occured on iOS 8. To reproduce the error, I downloaded the iOS 8.1 simulator and found the error. To get the exact error message, I went to Edit Scheme and Enabled Zombie Objects. That showed me the exact error message:

```
*** -[NamedUISwitch _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]: message sent to deallocated instance
```